Adding 3 & 4 way switches to detached structure
first time poster here.
To my barn I have run in a 1-1/2" PVC conduit, 3 wire 6AWG thhn2 feeder wires plus ground (240V) for a subpanel and 3 wire 12 AWG thhn2 plus ground (120V) for a 3 way switch lighting circuit powered from the main panel. All wires are copper. The feeders terminate in the sub but the 3 way switching is where I am spinning my wheels.
The circuit from my main panel will have two 3 way switches and possibly a 4 way. One in the house and one in the barn to control one exterior and one interior light simultaneously at the barn. The circuit power will go through the first switch in the house then to the second switch in the barn and then the 2 lights which will be hard wired to each other.
My confusion is as follows:

Branch circuit vs. single circuit. From what I have read, code allows 1 feeder or one branch circuit to provide power to an outbuilding. It has been stated that a 3 way switch circuit is a single and not a branch circuit because not all of the traveler wires are hot all of the time. Additionally I think I read that because it’s a switching circuit it’s technically not providing power to the building per se. The semantics can be a burden at times.

A means of disconnect in the barn for the lighting circuit that will not be connected to the sub.
I’ve seen parts of the code online that says a general purpose or snap switch can be used and I’ve also read the opposite that they cannot be used. Is “general purpose” just a regular light switch?

The requirement to have the grounded conductor at each switch.
I haven’t seen any diagrams that facilitate this configuration for the number of wires I have buried but I believe I read there are exceptions to this.


A. Only one switch has to have the grounded conductor IF it is visible from anywhere in the room or it is the first switch after the main panel.
B. Switches do not have to have the grounded conductor if they are in an uninhabitable area. Such as a barn in my case. I’ve read both that this is and isn’t to code.
Of this information what is accurate? Reading the NEC articles seem vague if not subjective and open to any number of interpretations.
Attached is a diagram that shows what I think will work and be compliant. FWIW, there are no inspections where I am located but still I want to be safe.


Questions should be presented in separate questions.

TLDR: The one-feeder rule is a general summary, but many exceptions exist. See the actual rule in 225.30(E):

225.30 Number of Supplies A building or other structure that is served by a branch circuit or feeder on the load side of a service
disconnecting means shall be supplied by only one feeder or branch
circuit unless permitted in 225.30(A) through (F)...
(E) Different Characteristics Additional feeders or branch circuits shall be permitted for different voltages, frequencies, or
phases, or for different uses such as control of outside lighting from
multiple locations.

I think "such as" could be broad enough for your situation.
Also note 225.31 that requires a disconnect where it enters the barn, and requires disconnects to be grouped together. So you need to add a two pole disconnect on the travelers located near the main feeder disconnect. A general purpose "light" switch is a "snap switch", and is acceptable in 225.36:

225.36 Type of Disconnecting Means The disconnecting means specified in 225.31 shall be a circuit breaker, molded case switch,
general-use switch, snap switch, or other approved means. Where
applied in accordance with 250.32(B)(1), Exception No. 1, the
disconnecting means shall be suitable for use as service equipment.

As far a neutral at switching, 404.2(C):

(C) Switches Controlling Lighting Loads The grounded circuit conductor for the controlled lighting circuit shall be installed at
the location where switches control lighting loads that are supplied
by a grounded general-purpose branch circuit serving bathrooms,
hallways, stairways, and habitable rooms or occupiable spaces as
defined in the applicable building code. Where multiple switch
locations control the same lighting load such that the entire floor
area of the room or space is visible from the single or combined
switch locations, the grounded circuit conductor shall only be
required at one location...

Your barn is "occupiable space".

Thank you for the information. Looks like due to character limitations I have to reply several times to you.
(E) certainly does look to be an applicable exception.
“Also note 225.31 that requires a disconnect where it enters the barn, and requires disconnects to be grouped together…”
This is what I envisioned I would need to do hence the 4 way switch as a traveler disconnect to the next in line 3 way switch. My interpretation is it needs to be isolated from the sub and a separate plastic switch box mounted to the wall near the sub is a solution that makes it easy to be compliant.

“Where multiple switch locations control the same lighting load such that the entire floor area of the room or space is visible from the single or combined switch locations, the grounded circuit conductor shall only be required at one location...”
I interpret(ed) the “OR combined switch locations” as the barn light switch and/or the 4 way being, even though remote, the combined switches which just need to have floor visual and therefore the switch in the house near the main panel could carry the grounded conductor.

However, if what 404.2© really means in my situation the house switch being the only one carrying the grounded conductor will not be in compliance then this will be a challenge. The power source is coming from the main through the 3 way in the house.

I don’t know if they exist or if it’s electrically possible but to do this with my existing infrastructure I would need 3 & 4 way switches with integrated neutral connections for the barn the way I see it at the moment.
A smart switch isn’t even in play because for one, I am off grid and I need to mindful of power management and two, I want my systems to be as mechanical as possible so if something does fail I can at least be able to try and it fix it myself.

Or article 404.2c could mean the grounded conductor just needs to be present and readily available for future use, not necessarily physically connected to the switch?
I read it that way too since it doesn’t specify connectivity.

(1)Most of the NEC references are hyperlinked you you can read the full paragraphs. Neutral isn't required to be connected to switch. If you continue to read the full paragraph of 404.2(C) you can see that if raceways are used there just has to be conduit capacity to add neutral if a switching device needs it. (2) A DPST switch is needed to disconnect both travelers, a four way will still leave one traveler in the next switch box hot

Also just noticed your example shows "Romex" between buildings. NM cable (Romex is a brand of NM cable) is not allowed in damp or wet location, and inside a conduit in a wet or damp location is still a damp or wet location. (I guess I'm just guessing that between buildings is as least damp)

The drawing doesn’t show it but wires between the pull boxes is thhn2 and is wet location suitable according the label. From the pull boxes to the switches and beyond I am using NM 14/3. As I understand it for wiring purposes any location outside of a structure even if in conduit is considered wet.
Thanks for the info. From the suggestions here I will be using a DPST switch and will install it in a switch box after the travelers transition to the 14/3.

The far better way to do this (which almost everyone does) is to flip the 3-way circuit so its power supply comes from the barn sub panel and not the house.  That way, the barn's single disconnect turns it off and you don't need to mess with 230.85 and grouped and labeled disconnects.
If you insist on powering the 3-way from the house, the problem is you can't just use a switch as a disconnect, because you have 2 hot wires in the 3-way travelers.  So you'll need a DPST switch, or more likely just a pullout disconnect, and it needs to be grouped with the sub panel main breaker.  (or if the sub panel does not have a main breaker and is relying on the "Rule of Six hand throws", the 3-way disconnect counts as one of the hand throws).  That's just not worth the trouble.
The wires in a 3-way/4-way setup are the same physical wires regardless of whether it is fed from one end or the other.
Note that if you interpret 404.2(C) as requiring neutral at these switches, you can't just grab any nearby neutral.  Neutral must run with the other wires.  However neutral doesn't need to be installed in a conduit since it can be easily added later.

While I trust you regarding the disconnect, I'm not so sure about "wires are the same". House -> Switch -> Switch -> Lights at and in outbuilding is easy: /3 with 2 travelers + neutral. But if you do Subpanel -> Switch -> Switch -> Lights at and in outbuilding then you end up with 2 travelers + switched hot - in which case you don't have neutral at switch 2 (arguably OK because it is conduit so you could add neutral later) or you end up running 2 travelers + switched hot + neutral which is an extra wire. Not the end of the world, and not nearly so bad with conduit as with cables (where

you would have to change from a /3 to a /4) but definitely not "exactly the same". A 20A double-pole switch will cost all of $8 at Home Depot, possibly less elsewhere, plus add a box (or an extra gang to another box) and you're set.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact because I don't agree that neutral is required.  It was never imagined for inter-building controls like this, and there are smart switch arrangements available which will work fine on /3 up the spur.

Key is "conduit" - so if it is wired your way then neutral could always be added.

The neutrals will be present and connected in series to each other at each switch location from the light to the main panel.
Thanks for the heads up on the DPST. I’m going with that instead of the 4 way which I mistakenly believed functioned differently that it does.

As I understand it, you can have multiple circuits between the buildings provide they serve different purposes. In particular, a 3-way switched circuit with switches at both buildings is by definition going to have to overlap with the feeder. Either it comes from the main panel (as you diagrammed it) or it comes from the subpanel (in which case it is "opposite" direction from the feeder) but really no difference. What you can't generally do is to have two non-switched circuits - e.g., a 15A for lights and a 20A for receptacles, though for that specific combination an MWBC solves the problem.
The diagram looks very good. The key is that white is carried along through all the switch boxes - that's the "grounded conductor". There are 3-way switch configurations done differently, but this does it in a way that nobody can argue. And it means if you later want to put in smart switches that need neutral you are all set.
Note that you actually need THWN because outside = wet, but most THHN wire is now also THWN anyway.
As far as the travelers only in use one at a time, that is relevant for derating based on the number of conductors in the conduit. If I understand the rules correctly, neutral does not count in a 3-wire circuit (your subpanel feeder) but does count in an ordinary circuit, and the travelers only count as 1 wire because only 1 can be hot at a time. So that means 4 conductors and an 80% derate from the 90 degree column.
For the 12 AWG that's easy - that would be copper and 0.8 x 30A = 24A which is more than the 20A that you can use anyway.
For the 6 AWG, that depends on copper vs. aluminum. You should be using aluminum because that is much cheaper at large sizes and is normal for subpanel feeders. But the question didn't say, so:

Copper, 6 AWG 90 C = 75A. 0.8 x 75A = 60A, which is a little less than the default 75 C 65A rating.
Aluminum, 6 AWG 90 C = 55A. 0.8 x 55A = 44A, which is a little less than the default 75 C 50A rating.

So the wire size depends on the type and on how much power you need. Here are several of the options from 6 AWG up:

Copper - 6 AWG - 60A
Copper - 4 AWG - 76A
Copper - 3 AWG - 92A
Copper - 2 AWG - 104A
Aluminum 6 AWG - 44A
Aluminum 4 AWG - 60A
Aluminum 3 AWG - 68A
Aluminum 2 AWG - 80A

You should also need only one ground wire. However, it may be easier to include a separate smaller ground for the switched lighting circuit. But keep in mind that if you use metal boxes then ground goes to the boxes rather than to the devices and that switches get ground automatically from the boxes. So a 10 AWG copper ground (feeder up to 60A) or 8 AWG copper ground (up to 100A) can take care of everything.
Putting all of this together, I would recommend sizing the conduit for one of two options:
60A feeder

3 x 4 AWG aluminum (feeder)
3 x 12 AWG copper (switched circuit)
1 x 10 AWG copper (ground)

which should work fine with 1" PVC (schedule 40). With schedule 80 you would need 1-1/4", but if most of the run is underground then schedule 80 is only needed for the verticals.
or
80A feeder

3 x 2 AWG aluminum (feeder)
3 x 12 AWG copper (switched circuit)
1 x 8 AWG copper (ground)

which should work fine with 1-1/4" PVC (schedule 40 or 80)
Also remember:

You will need ground rods at the barn
Neutral and ground not bonded in the barn panel
Do two Load Calculations before you buy anything: one for the main service to determine how much capacity is available for the barn and another for the barn to figure out how much capacity you need at the barn. If the numbers don't work then come back with specifics about existing and planned equipment and there may be ways to solve it without a heavy-up.


Thank you for the very detailed in depth response. For the sake of brevity I omitted many details of my config in my post which I’ll share.
First though, your comment about the neutrals and smart switches cast a new perspective of the code requirement. I was stuck on the notion they had to somehow be actively connected to the switches and never considered that just their presence in the box satisfied code. That’s how I interpret it now after reviewing 404.2C. “grounded circuit conductor shall only be required at one location” Operative word is “Location”  Thanks for mentioning that.

My system: Off grid 9000 watt which gives me 37.5A load capability. I have a 60A breaker in the main to the sub which has its own 100A breaker. The largest load I anticipate at any one moment in time will be is ~ 18A @240v for a possible future 4 post vehicle lift.

The 1-1/2” PVC already is already run and populated with all copper 6 & 12 AWG thhn. @3+ for both gauges. The thhn is rated @90c but I calc’d my load capacity and breaker size for in between 60 & 75 just for added assurance the circuits don’t overheat the wires. The sub is a 20/40 so I have ample circuit capacity for the future. Every circuit at this point is going to be wired with 14AWG nm at the barn. No N-G bonding at the sub

I will have GFCI protected strings for outlets on each of the three walls. I’m considering attaching the 2 door openers to two of those circuits on their respective side. 1 other circuit will power an overhead LED flood light independent of the 3 way circuit. The current plan is to add 2 strings of 4 panel LED lights, 3 in each string and drawing ~ 4A per complete fixture for a total of 24A when all are energized. I may need to go 2 per string at first then decide to add later. Since I want to add a mini split in the house I’m probably going to need to stack another inverter.

I will be adding a GES at the barn and possibly a LPS too. The main panel in the house is grounded to the 4 rod array lightning protection system with 8AWG via a bus bar with 2.5 Ohms to ground between the UFER and rods when last checked. I recently started to research if I need to tie them (2 LPS’s) together because of the Main-sub connectivity. First thought is yes to protect the wires from any difference in potential between the 2 systems in the case of a strike, but then I think getting the voltage to ground in the shortest path possible gives me that protection.

However, the barn to LPS system at the house is ~140’ which is not much in terms of an inductive ground voltage spike from said lightning and could go sideways on me no matter what I attempt.
Sorry, I’m starting to get a little long winded and off topic but I thank you again for the detailed response!

Extra info is always good. Based on what you described, due to supply limitations you'll never exceed the wire and breaker size limits. But be careful about 14AWG nm - that's fine for 15A circuits but NOT for 20A circuits. A 20A circuit - even if each individual receptacle is a 15A receptacle (which is common and perfectly legit) must use 20A rated == 12 AWG wire or cable.

Indeed.  All are 15A receptacles right now. I will definitely be sizing wire appropriately for anything larger.
